# Ceil positive float and floor negative float

Tags: c#

Is there a shorter way of doing this instead of checking whether the float is positive or not and do the if statement as following? (Using Unity5 with c# script)

Expecting

1.0, 1.4, 1.7 => 2 (I figured that Ceil 1.0 yields 1.. any help with this too?)

-1.0, -1.4, -1.7 => -2 (Floor -1.0 yields -1..)

```
if (float < 0) {
    Mathf.Floor (float);
} else {
    Mathf.Ceil (float);
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: why is your expectation that 1.0 => 2 and -1.0 => -2?

Comment: Random question: what would be wrong with: `var result = (int)(val < 0 ? Mathf.Floor(val) : Mathf.Ceil(val));` ?

Comment: Hi, I didn't expect it to be like that. It was a silly question but it is solved. Just stated what I wanted to happen..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

```
Mathf.Sign(x)*Mathf.Ceil(Mathf.Abs(x))
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Didn't know Sign(x) exist! Any help with Flooring and Ceiling integers? (1.0 => 2) Thanks!